# MYSQL full join 4 tables using a reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help building a SQL to fetch something like a "FULL OUTER JOIN" over four tables. I have this structure and cannot really modify much on it, cause its a already in use database:

[image]

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for article
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `article`  (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (1, 'Coffeemaker');
INSERT INTO `article` VALUES (2, 'Toaster');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for language
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `language`  (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
INSERT INTO `language` VALUES (1, 'German');
INSERT INTO `language` VALUES (2, 'English');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for property
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `property`  (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
INSERT INTO `property` VALUES (1, 'DescriptionText');
INSERT INTO `property` VALUES (2, 'EAN-Code');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for data
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `data`  (
  `ArticleID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PropertyID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `LanguageID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ArticleID`, `PropertyID`, `LanguageID`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ArticleID` FOREIGN KEY (`ArticleID`) REFERENCES `article` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LanguageID` FOREIGN KEY (`LanguageID`) REFERENCES `language` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PropertyID` FOREIGN KEY (`PropertyID`) REFERENCES `property` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `data` VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Eine Kaffemaschine');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'A toaster');
```

SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91dc8/1

What i want to get is a new VIEW which contains a join over all entity-tables showing a row for all articles, all properties and all languages but using the already existing data if available or null if not.

[image]

Is it possible? How would the SQL look like?

Comment: What do you mean by all articles and all languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be after this...

```
SELECT a.id articleid
     , p.id propertyid
     , l.id languageid
     , d.value 
  FROM article a
 CROSS -- optional keyword
  JOIN property p
 CROSS -- optional keyword
  JOIN language l 
  LEFT -- not optional
  JOIN data d
    ON d.articleid = a.id
   AND d.propertyid = p.id
   AND d.languageid = l.id;

+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
| articleid | propertyid | languageid | value              |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
|         1 |          1 |          1 | Eine Kaffemaschine |
|         2 |          1 |          1 | NULL               |
|         1 |          2 |          1 | NULL               |
|         2 |          2 |          1 | NULL               |
|         1 |          1 |          2 | NULL               |
|         2 |          1 |          2 | A toaster          |
|         1 |          2 |          2 | NULL               |
|         2 |          2 |          2 | NULL               |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Looks about right! What is the magic? Is JOIN working different to INNER JOIN? Currently a bit confused.

Comment: These are cross joins/cartesian products (where no relationship is identified between the joined tables). So the first two joins simply return every possible combination of ids, and then the LEFT JOIN identifies which of those actually exist in `data`

Comment: Understood! Didn't knew about this join type. Is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for explanation and the helpful answer.

Comment: You can add the keyword `CROSS` if it helps clarify, but MySQL doesn't care one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all *articles*, you don't want a "full join".  You want a `left join` that starts with the `articles` table.  Further, you don't even need that, because all your articles have values in data.

But the question does specify all articles, so:

```
SELECT a.*, p.*, l.*, d.*
FROM article a LEFT JOIN
     data d 
     ON d.ArticleID = a.ID LEFT JOIN
     property p
     ON d.PropertyID = p.id LEFT JOIN
     language l
     ON d.LanguageID = l.id;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by all articles and all languages (I missed the second part when I first read the question).  If you want all combinations then:

```
SELECT a.*, p.*, l.*, d.*
FROM article a CROSS JOIN
     languages l LEFT JOIN
     data d 
     ON d.ArticleID = a.ID AND
        d.LanguageID = l.ID LEFT JOIN
     property p
     ON d.PropertyID = p.id ;
```

Comment: The result of that SQL are only 2 rows for the 2 articles, but missing out the results for each property and language. Or do i get your answer wrong?

Comment: @gordon-linoff thanks for the edit. Its going in the right direction like strawberry's answer and i think you are suggesting the same functionality.